# How to keep both components from XML and those added programatically

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android.

I am drawing Textfield using drag-drop from Eclipse.

Also adding a Table programatically.

But I can see only table which is added programatically.

How to keep both components from XML and those added programatically.

Sorry if it is a really basic and stupid question.

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ZoomButton
        android:id="@+id/zoomButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_plus" />

    <ZoomControls
        android:id="@+id/zoomControls1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TwoLineListItem
        android:id="@+id/twoLineListItem1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <AbsoluteLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </AbsoluteLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <AnalogClock
        android:id="@+id/analogClock1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</TableLayout>
```

and

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    //To insert
   // db.addContact(new Contact("Ninad", "9893353432"));

    TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);
    table.setStretchAllColumns(true);
    table.setShrinkAllColumns(true);

    TableRow rowTitle = new TableRow(this);
    rowTitle.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

    TableRow rowDayLabels = new TableRow(this);



    // title column/row
    TextView title = new TextView(this);
    title.setText("Contacts");
    title.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 18);
    title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    title.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);

    TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
    params.span = 3;
    rowTitle.addView(title, params);




    // Header 1
    TextView header1 = new TextView(this);
    header1.setText("ID");
    header1.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);
    rowDayLabels.addView(header1);


    // Header 2
    TextView header2 = new TextView(this);
    header2.setText("NAME");
    header2.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);
    rowDayLabels.addView(header2);

    // Header 3
    TextView header3 = new TextView(this);
    header3.setText("PHONE");
    header3.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD);
    rowDayLabels.addView(header3);

 // Add to Table
    table.addView(rowTitle);
    table.addView(rowDayLabels);

    List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();       
    TableRow rowHighs = null;
 for (Contact cn : contacts) {

     rowHighs = new TableRow(this);
    // Data
    TextView day1High = new TextView(this);
    day1High.setText(String.valueOf(cn.getID()));
    rowHighs.addView(day1High);

    TextView day2High = new TextView(this);
    day2High.setText(cn.getName());
    rowHighs.addView(day2High);

    TextView day3High = new TextView(this);
    day3High.setText(cn.getPhoneNumber());
    rowHighs.addView(day3High);

    table.addView(rowHighs);
 }


    setContentView(table);
}
```

My Table in the `OnCreate` method is populated properly, but components from XML are lost.

**Update :**

What I found is, I am setting it two times and later one is overwritting it

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

setContentView(table);
```

But how can I merge it ?

Comment: can you please post code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type in your activity below oncreate

```
TableLayout tbl_lay=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tablelayout1);
.....
.....
.....
Your Code.....
TableLayout tb=new TableLayout(this);
.....
.....
```

atlast add these line

```
tbl_lay.addview(tb);
```

it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Your layout name is "tableLayout1" in xml, you should implement a TableLayout object from it by using findViewById, and add your programmatically created view to it. Be careful about positioning, you may put it on your drag-drop views!

```
TableLayout myLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
//your elements created
myLayout.addView(yourCreatedViewElement);
```

Comment: But at a time I can use only one right? - `setContentView(table)` or `setContentView(R.id.tableLayout1)` how to add both ?

Comment: You can use setContentView(anyView) anytime, but whenever you do, you will change layout you see with new one. You should setContentView(yourXMLcreatedView) and than put it's main Layout to an object just as i wrote. After that, you can add your programmatically created views to it, you don't have to use setContentView again.